# Form validation using $touched and $error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I'm trying to implement client-side validation using [built-in validation mechanisms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) provided by AngularJS.

I've a simple input of type `email` which must display an error if the email is invalid once the form get submitted using `$submitted` or once the control has lost focus using `$touched`.

```
<form name="form" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input-emailaddress">Adresse email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="input-emailaddress" placeholder="Entrez votre email" ng-model="user.email" required="required">
        <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.input-emailaddress.$touched">
            <div ng-show="form.input-emailaddress.$error.email">Please insert a valid email address.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

But there's no error triggered when I type an invalid email address. `$submitted` works fine cause if I remove every other conditions, the message appears once triggered, but when I need to access a specific field (`form.input-emailaddress`), validation does not work.

Does anyone could help me figure out why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are accessing JSON object using `.` at that time you variable shouldn't contain any character like `-` or shouldn't be started with numeric variable. You should do access `form.input-emailaddress` like `form["input-emailaddress"]`
because it contains hyphen in name will not work

**Update**

As per @SunilD suggestion we could have change name to should not follow in such crieteria you could use cammel case instead of doing this

Comment: Or better yet change the name of the input to remove the hyphen, so you don't have to work around the hyphen :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the mistake and I changed the name, you made my day! Gonna mark your answer as accepted in 9 minutes ;)

Comment: @SunilD. added your suggested change in answer..thanks for suggestion.:)